# how many infinite cardinals are smaller than $\aleph$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

What can be said in general (if we do not assume the continuum hypothesis) about the cardinality of the set of all infinite cardinals smaller than $\aleph$?

Comment: The cardinality of $\{\aleph_\alpha \colon \aleph_\alpha < \aleph_\beta\}$ is $\operatorname{card} \beta$, independently of the (generalised) continuum hypothesis. Now, given an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, finding $\beta$ with $\kappa = \aleph_\beta$, that could be difficult.

Comment: @Daniel: $\aleph$ often denotes $2^{\aleph_0}$. It was Cantor's notation (although at first he also used a Gothic letter, I think $\frak v$ actually, not $\frak c$). In Israel it's not uncommon to see introductory courses to set theory using $\aleph$ as the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Interesting, didn't know that (obviously). Thanks for the info.

Comment: Also, tipshoni, have you checked anything on the site before? I am certain this was answered at least three times before.

Comment: @Asaf Apparently $\aleph$ has been used for $\mathfrak c$ for ages. Hausdorff does it in his 1901 paper *Über eine gewisse Art geordneter Mengen*. In Plotkin's translation, he says that the cardinality of certain set "is equal to the cardinality $\aleph$ of the continuum" and, in a footnote, "Since G. Cantor intends to publish a proof soon that each transfinite cardinal number must occur in the `sequence of alephs,' there is less reason to avoid this temporary notation (aleph without an index) as prejudicial."

Comment: @Andrés: Thanks for the historical piece of data!

Answer (score 11):

I assume by $\aleph$ you mean the continuum, the size of the reals, which is more commonly denoted $\mathfrak c$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$.

There is no bound, actually. Meaning, it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\kappa=\kappa$ for some (necessarily limit) ordinal $\kappa$, so there are $\kappa$ (that is, continuum many) infinite cardinals below the continuum. Of course, we cannot have more than this. (That is, relative to its size, it can be as large as possible.)

More can be said: If $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\beta$, then either $\beta$ is a successor ordinal, or it is a limit ordinal of cofinality larger than $\omega$. This follows from [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29).

Solovay showed, in the very early days of forcing, that in a sense this is all we can say: Starting with a model of $\mathsf{GCH}$, we can pick *any* ordinal $\beta$ satisfying those two restrictions, and force to obtain a model with the same cofinalities (and cardinals, and ordinals) as the ground model, and where $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\beta$. (That is, in absolute terms, there is no bound.)

This was announced in

> Robert M. Solovay. *Independence results in the theory of cardinals. I, II* (abstracts). Notices of the AMS, **10**, (1963), 595,

and appeared as

> Robert M. Solovay. *$2^{\aleph_0}$ can be anything it ought to be*, in **The Theory of Models**, Proceedings of the 1963 International Symposium at Berkeley. Amsterdam, North-Holland, 1965, Addison, Henkin, Tarski, eds., pg. 435.

What he needs to obtain in the extension that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\beta$ is that, in the ground model, $\aleph_\beta^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\beta$, which of course follows from $\mathsf{GCH}$ if $\beta$ is successor or limit of uncountable cofinality.

So, to summarize: The continuum, in "absolute" terms, can be as large as you want. In relative terms as well: There can be continuum many cardinals below. And it can be any $\aleph_\beta$ at all, as long as the restriction given by König's theorem that $\mathrm{cf}(\mathfrak c)>\omega$ is satisfied.

The other question we could ask is whether $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be weakly inaccessible (that is, regular limit). The answer is positive (Solovay's argument does not change any cofinalities), but more is possible: It can even be *[real-valued measurable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable)*, which implies that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\kappa=\kappa$ for some regular $\kappa$ such that there are $\kappa$ weakly inaccessibles below (that are limit of weakly inaccessibles that themselves are limit of weakly inaccessibles...), it implies that there is an extension of Lebesgue measure defined on all sets of reals, and more. And it is consistent as well that the continuum satisfies various strengthenings of this notion.

Comment: We don't need $\sf GCH$ if we just want to blow up the continuum, don't we?

Comment: No, of course not. I would have to check Solovay's paper to see if this was his assumption.

Comment: Since Solovay wanted to get the cardinal of the continuum to be anything it ought to be, he probably assumed GCH in the ground model so that he can reach anything by merely blowing up the continuum.  (Another reason to assume GCH and maybe even V=L is that, in the very early days of forcing, that's what one did. Solovay was one of the first to break away from that style, but I'm not sure whether he did so in this paper.)