# Can the continuum $\mathfrak c$ be a limit cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Can the continuum $\mathfrak c$ be a limit cardinal?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: According to Wiki, I think there are at least two notions of limit cardinals. $\mathfrak c$ seems to be reachable by taking the power set of $\aleph_0$, but not by successor operation without the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/444279/462).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  The only restriction is that $\mathfrak{c}$ must be a cardinal of uncountable cofinality.  So $\mathfrak{c}$ can be $\aleph_{\omega_1}$, but not $\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: This answers the question I was about to ask. The continuum cannot be \aleph_\omega, for some reason. Good thing I checked. Now I'll have to do research to find out why.